# Why wouldn't a Google Analytics template sharing link work for one person on my team

Tags: google-analytics, template

There is a shared custom report in Google Analytics of this format:

```
https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/template?uid=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

4 persons from my team clicked at the link and tried to open it:

3 of them can see the page **A Custom Report configuration was shared with you.** with the button **Create**.

but the 4th (who certainly has more permissions) sees a loading screen and then gets redirected to his dashboard.

Do you have any idea what could be the issue?

ps. If i re-click the link, I still get the "create" page, although I have it created. So, the answer is not "maybe he has it already created".

Comment: Does the 4th person have multiple Google accounts? S/he could be logging into GA with wrong account.

Answer (score 1):

Try sharing the template link on "custom reports" -->"actions"--->"Share".

The custom report needs to be shared. Sharing the dashboard itself will not include custom reports.